# SSRS 2012 report - strange behavior of locked columns and rows

Tags: scroll, locking, ssrs-2012

I create report on SSRS 2012 and display in web browser (IE, FF). On the report is some rows and cols locked (fixedData property in designer). Scrolling report with both scrollbars, upper left part of table behaves strange. 
Strange behavior apears only on first page. On second and other pages is everything OK. When scrolling with only one scrollbar, table is OK too.

Image shows problem part of report displaying.

[Bad report displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNYzp.png)

Correct report displaying on second page

[Correct behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Amk.png)

Is there some solution? Or do I something wrong?

Comment: Hi Marek, this usually occurs when multiple tables or textboxes used are overlapped while designing. Are you using different table or textboxes for header row?

Comment: Hi. I was not created multiple talbles. But multiple tables are probably created by SSRS as fixed rows / cols. - And on second page works everything fine. So problem is somwhere else. Maybe some space above table (on first page), maybe something hidden. I don't know yet.